# Gmail "InternalDateSource" query parameter not working?

Tags: gmail-api

I am using the "insert" API to add a message to Gmail, and using the query parameter internalDateSource=dateHeader.  However Gmail seems to ignore the "Date" header that is in my RFC822 data, just substituting the current date. My POST url looks like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/user@gmail.com/messages?uploadType=multipart&internalDateSource=dateHeader&access_token=XYZ
```

My uploaded data looks like this:

```
{
 "labelIds": [ "Label_96" ],
  "raw": "RnJvbTo...tDQr_"
}
```

There is no doubt that the correct "Date" header is in the encoded raw
data. (Here is an example):

```
Date: Wed, 1 Oct 2011 10:47:00 -08:00
```

Google picks up all the other headers and message data correctly.  What am I doing wrong?  BTW I did try adding "payload" and "headers" to my json in an attempt to specify a Date header.  No change.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your `Date`-header. It should be:

```
Date: Wed, 1 Oct 2011 10:47:00 -0800
```

not

```
Date: Wed, 1 Oct 2011 10:47:00 -08:00
```